# How to get change event in input field for a directive in angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I am a bit new to angular 4. I am trying to get change event from an input field inside a directive. Currently i am working with @HostListener

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  inputChanged(event) {}
```

This is working correctly but this event is fired after some delay from releasing key and user can enter wrong input and is able to see that too. In my implementation i have removed the invalid input but it doesn't give a good exposure to user. Only thing i want is to get change event right the moment change happen in input field (character / string enter or remove both ).
Current HTML looks like this

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" placeHolder='hh:mm:ss' time-input [(ngModel)]="params.time" name="time"/>
```

*PS.* time-input is the name of directive and in directive i am trying to get the event change and i don't want to move any implementation to controller or component.

Comment: do you want to get native DOM event or event from `ngModel` directive?

Comment: i don't have any restriction for using any event type.i was using native DOM event at first but there was a problem in that but @gunter's answer worked and it is according requirements now

Comment: you need `input` event for the DOM native element. Gunter's solution will only work if there's `ngModel` directive on the `input`. So your `time-input` will only work alongside `ngModel`, it can't be used as a standalone directive

Comment: ok got it now i have two way i can cake ngModel necessory for that directive second update event (ngModelChange) to input event. Thanks for guidance. i will do it.:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: what If I'm not using ngModel?

Comment: @anaval you can also listen to `'input'` or `'change'` events fired by the input element directly. See also the end ofhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: What if the change in value was not triggered by the user? Like reactive forms when the app dynamically sets the value of a forms

Comment: Then there is no event. You can call your even handlers yourself from the code that changes the values.